# How to create nestable object

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls

At the begining I would like to say hello, so ... Hello. I need to create a nested object structure. 
I've got an object (xaml page) like this

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="ItemTemplateExample.ContentItem" 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
       d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="20"
       Title="ContentItem Page">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="button1" />
    <ContentControl  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="content1" />
</Grid>
```

Now I would like to use it in nested structure. For Example

```
<local:ContentItem ButtonText="level 1">
     <local:ContentItem ButtonText="level 2" />
     <local:ContentItem ButtonText="level 2" />
     <local:ContentItem ButtonText="level 2">
          <local:ContentItem ButtonText="level 3" />    
     </local:ContentItem>
</local:ContentItem>
```

Where ButtonText will be known value (set when adding nested object) and Content of each object will be object of the same type. I have no idea how to start. Please give me some hint, exmaples. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would like to see HierarchicalDataTemplate in WPF

[Seee here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)

Comment: Finnaly, I 've  used treeview with my own templete. It was so easy if I know what to search.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions: a user control or a data template. The user control is probably the simplest to get to from where you are now, but the data template may be a better solution in the long run.

Adding a user control to a project is straightforward - Visual Studio has a template for that. You could just put the exact same `Grid` you've shown here inside your `ContentItem` user control's Xaml. And then you'd just need to define a property called `ButtonText` in the codebehind of your user control. This should do it:

```
public string ButtonText
{
    get { return button1.Content.ToString(); }
    set { button1.Content = value; }
}
```

That should let you use Xaml more or less exactly like you've shown.

The reason I'm suggesting that a data template might be better is that you might not want to hard-code the nested structure in Xaml. It's often nice to be able to generate such structure from data rather than baking it into the UI. However, if your structure is completely fixed, the approach you've asked for is probably OK.

Comment: Thank You, but i've expected something different.

Comment: What did you expect, and in what way would you like it to be different? I'd like to be helpful, but your feedback isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related:[Example of Nested Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780483/is-it-possible-to-nest-collections-within-collections-using-wpf-datagrid/3780533#3780533)